# Dynamically assigning a parameter to a RelayCommand in MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, relaycommand

I've seen quite a few example of passing a parameter through a command using the RelayCommand class in MVVM Light, but there's one slight difference between what i want and what i have seen.

I want to create a few buttons where all have them have a ModuleType associated. And when their action is executed i want to know which ModuleType it is. And i wanted to do this in a code efficient way, so not having to create the RelayCommands manually, but instead do everything in a foreach loop, also because i don't know how many buttons i have to create at start.

So here is the code. In my **ViewModel**

```
public ModuleSelectionViewModel(MachineStatusModel model, int order, List<ModuleType> modules) : base(model)
{
    ........

    // create button for each of the modules
    foreach (ModuleType mod in modules)
    {
        _navBarButtons.Add(new NavButton(mod.ToString(), new RelayCommand<ModuleType>(exec => ButtonExecute(mod)), mod));
    }

    RaisePropertyChanged("NavBarButtons");
}


// Binding to the Model
public ObservableCollection<NavButton> NavBarButtons
{
    get { return _navBarButtons; }
}


// Execut Action
public void ButtonExecute(ModuleType mod)
{
    WriteToLog("Selected " + mod.ToString());
}


// Support class
public class NavButton
{
    public string ButtonContent { get; set; }
    public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; set; }
    public ModuleType ButtonModuleType;

    public NavButton(string content, ICommand relay, ModuleType moduleType)
    {
        this.ButtonContent = content;
        this.ButtonCommand = relay;
        this.ButtonModuleType = moduleType;
    }
}
```

I'm still learning about lambda expressions, so i guess i am doing something wrong on the initialization of the RelayCommand.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @DevNewb: in summary, i want to press a button and trigger the execute function with a parameter. Each button has a different value for that parameter

Comment: it's not clear from your question what exactly doesn't work in the code you provided

Comment: @DevNewb take a look at the discussion on the answer H.B. gave. At this point this part is not working 'param => ButtonExecute(type))', the ButtonExecute won't execute. I want it to execute that function with the parameter that was passed at the time of creation '... new RelayCommand<ModuleType>(param => ButtonExecute(type)) ...'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the solution H.B. posted: not sure why it was not working with lambda functions, why the ButtonExecute was not being execute when the button was pressed. And also i don't understand the logic of defining a lambda function like 'foo => ButtonExecute(foo)' when foo is empty and being passed to the function. But anyway...

This is what i did and is working:

**Model**

```
<ItemsControl Name="NavButtonsItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding NavBarButtons}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding ButtonContent}" CommandParameter="{Binding ButtonModuleType}" Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

**ViewModel** (check the rest of the code in my initial question)

```
.........

_navBarButtons.Add(new NavButton(mod.ToString(), new RelayCommand<ModuleType>(ButtonExecute), type));

.........

private void ButtonExecute(ModuleType state)
{
    WriteToLog("Command with parameter " + state.ToString());
}
```

You can make this more generic by using Object instead of ModuleType. And the solution, instead of using a lambda function, is defining a CommandParameter binding in the button and getting that value as the parameter in the execute function. I don't think that binding is explicitly defined, that's why i was having a hard time understanding how the value was reaching 'ButtonExecute', but following the steps in [Dominik Schmidt tutorial](http://www.dominikschmidt.net/2010/12/net-c-mvvm-relaycommand-with-parameters/) it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you do a `foreach` loop and use the *loop variable* inside a lambda expression you capture it. Unfortunately the variable is scoped incorrectly (at least in older versions of C#, this [changes with C# 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/) (thanks, Mafii)).

So you need to do something like:

```
foreach (ModuleType mod in modules)
{
    // New variable that is locally scoped.
    var type = mod;

    _navBarButtons.Add(new NavButton(mod.ToString(),
        new RelayCommand<ModuleType>(param => ButtonExecute(type)), type));
}
```

Comment: This is due to the closure principle. And it is still relevant AFAIK.

Comment: I think this has been fixed in .net 4.0, but I'm unsure. It is for sure fixed in .net 4.5

Comment: @WicherVisser ok, it's been fixed in c#5: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/

Comment: There's still a detail missing i guess. If i initialize with 'foo => ButtonExecute(foo)' (same variable on both sides, my ButtonExecute function is triggered, but with a default value 0. However if i do like you said 'exec => ButtonExecute(type)' then the function isn't triggered. Why is that?

Comment: @LuisFerreira: Lambda expressions are functions, any value on the left is assigned upon execution of the function, e.g. `x => x * x` squares whatever value is used as input. The function you pass here has the `CommandParameter` passed to it as input by the control that uses the command. So that parameter will be assigned accordingly. This is a prime use case for the `CommandParameter` by the way, just set it to you type and then you can use it in the function.

Comment: @H.B.: I understood that part about the Lambda expression, but the expression is defined locally, so i can't assign anything to foo, therefore if i do 'foo => ButtonExecute(foo)' i understand that the value inside of foo is trash. But i don't understand why this 'foo => ButtonExecute(type)'  doesn't trigger the method. So how can i pass the 'type' to the execute function?

Comment: @LuisFerreira: This passes the type to the execute function and just ignores the `CommandParameter`, though i cannot tell you why the command is not executed. It should execute either way.